# Process form data with Java

Tags: java, mysql, forms, servlets

I'm currently working on a Java web application which will take data submitted by a user (from a form) and write it to a database. The input page is a JSP file with lots of textboxes, dropdowns, textareas, etc. I would like to know how to go about processing data from the form and putting it into a database when the form could have a variable number of inputs.

I'll give you an example that illustrates my problem: A user has multiple phone numbers that they want to give us. On the form, there is a single input box for phone number, and an "add" button which uses JQuery to add another phone number input box. When the user submits the form, a servlet receives all the data. At this point, what is the most robust way to process this data so that I can add it to the database? My first thought would be to have the javascript increment the name of the phone number box (ex: "phonenumber1", "phonenumber2", etc) and have the servlet loop through the inputs, but it seems like their should be a more robust way to do it. I would really appreciate any advice I can get. Thanks!

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following:

```
String[] phonenumbers = request.getParameterValues("phonenumber")
```

see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29). It will return to you an array of all the fields named "phonenumber" in your form. You can eventually cycle the array and store it to your database.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getParameterNames();--phonenumber1,2,3
```

it will return all parameters Names

and iterate one by one that enum and get like this

```
request.getParameter(phonenumber1);--insert into DB
```